# Can Delphi themed toolbars have dividers that are centred between their tool buttons?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I have noticed a rather annoying oddity with Delphi toolbars. I have a `TToolbar` that has logical groups of icons. To make the grouping stand out I would like to use separator buttons, with style `tbsDivider`.

When I do this, it looks like this:

[image]

Note the double vertical lines between each icon. The right hand one is in the middle of the separator tool button. The left hand one is on the left edge of the separator tool button.

So, I can switch to `tbsSeparator` which removes the middle line:

[image]

But I'm not keen on that since I'd like the divider to be in the middle.

I looked at an ancient version of my real app and found that it had centred separators. It seems that is possible when Windows themes are disabled.  Here's what it looks like with `tbsDivider` and the application manifest removed:

[image]

That's the layout I am looking for. Is this attainable when themes are active?

I did find a discussion of the issue on the Embarcadero forums, but there was no useful insight: https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=467842

For sake of completeness, here's the pertinent extract from the .dfm file

```
object ToolButton1: TToolButton
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  ImageIndex = 0
end
object ToolButton2: TToolButton
  Left = 23
  Top = 0
  Width = 16
  ImageIndex = 1
  Style = tbsDivider
end
object ToolButton3: TToolButton
  Left = 39
  Top = 0
  ImageIndex = 1
end
object ToolButton4: TToolButton
  Left = 62
  Top = 0
  Width = 16
  ImageIndex = 2
  Style = tbsDivider
end
object ToolButton5: TToolButton
  Left = 78
  Top = 0
  ImageIndex = 2
end
```

Comment: I can confirm that this issue is also seen on my machine (Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit, Delphi 2009, themes enabled). The issue (if it is not obvious to everyone) is that the left-most line shouldn't be there. The separator should be completely blank, and the divider should have a single line in the middle.

Comment: Do you know if it is a VCL or a Windows issue?

Comment: This is both an MS Common controls issue AND a VCL flaw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The native control draws the vertical line for a separator button when the toolbar has the flat style. So if you remove the flat style, you'd be left alone with the VCL's *divider* line. You can safely remove the style when the application is themed, themed toolbar buttons does not regard flat style (why toolbar separators does, I have no idea). However when themes are disabled there'll again be two lines. In that case keeping separators instead of dividers seems like the better option.

One would guess unsetting the `Flat` property would have any effect as the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TToolBar.Flat) states. However `TToolBar.CreateParams` unconditionally enables it when `StyleServices` is enabled. So an API call is necessary;

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  TbStyle: DWORD;
begin
  if StyleServices.Enabled then begin
    TbStyle := SendMessage(ToolBar1.Handle, TB_GETSTYLE, 0, 0);
    SendMessage(Toolbar1.Handle, TB_SETSTYLE, 0, TbStyle and not TBSTYLE_FLAT);
  end;
end;
```

This eliminates part of the problem, the remaining part is the divider line is not exactly in the center between two buttons. VCL's problem here is, it does not want to draw the line itself. So it calls the theme api which draws the separator line to the left of the separator. To circumvent, VCL passes about the right half of the separator rectangle to the api, and the line gets *about* in the middle. I don't know if there's any way to tell exactly where the theme api draws it and I doubt there is.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a flaw in the VCL to me. The `tbsDivider` style does not map to an equivalent style in Win32. A tool button with that style is implemented in the VCL in just the same way as a `tbsSeparator` style, but with a custom paint method. This is extracted from `TToolButton.Paint`:

```
if Style = tbsDivider then
  with Canvas do
  begin
    R := Rect(Width div 2 - 1, 0, Width, Height);
    if StyleServices.Enabled then
    begin
      Details := StyleServices.GetElementDetails(ttbSeparatorNormal);
      StyleServices.DrawElement(Handle, Details, R);
    end
    else
      DrawEdge(Handle, R, EDGE_ETCHED, BF_LEFT)
  end;
```

In the old days of pre-v6 comctl32, the `tbsSeparator` style maps to a Win32 `TBSTYLE_SEP` style tool button. And in pre-v6 comctl32 that renders simply as a space with no vertical lines. The VCL designers clearly wanted to do more and added `tbsDivider` with the custom painting above.

Fast forward to v6 comctl32. Now the common control draws a vertical line at the left hand edge of all `TBSTYLE_SEP` separators. So the code above simply adds an extra vertical line in the middle of the separator.

We can try to get rid of the left-hand vertical line from a `tbsDivider` by modifying the code like this:

```
if Style = tbsDivider then
  with Canvas do
  begin
    if StyleServices.Enabled then
    begin
      //re-paint the background to remove the vertical line drawn
      //for the standard separator button
      R := Rect(0, 0, Width, Height);
      StyleServices.DrawParentBackground(FToolBar.Handle, Handle, nil, False, R);
    end;

    R := Rect(Width div 2 - 1, 0, Width, Height);
    if StyleServices.Enabled then
    begin
      Details := StyleServices.GetElementDetails(ttbSeparatorNormal);
      StyleServices.DrawElement(Handle, Details, R);
    end
    else
      DrawEdge(Handle, R, EDGE_ETCHED, BF_LEFT)
  end;
```

However, that doesn't work out because there's a lot of flickering as the left hand line is drawn and then painted over.

I suspect that the VCL designers simply missed this arcane detail in the transition to v6 comctl32.

I'll submit a QC report in due course.

Comment: +1 I suppose Microsoft's rationale for drawing a line along the left-most edge is that separator buttons are very thin, like a pixel or two wide? It is interesting that [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760439(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't mention the line.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Sadly my fix doesn't work. Flicker as we draw the left hand line, and then erase it. So the only way round would be to suppress the left hand line somehow........

Comment: Have you tried to create a plain Win32 application with a toolbar (without using the VCL)? I am just curious how that would look.

Comment: @Andreas I have not but it is clear enough from the VCL code what it would look like.

Comment: A 1 px line to the left? But if the separator button has width > 1, this will look bad, and although regular toolbars has been somewhat 'deprecated' over the last years, I find it hard to believe that a standard Windows control has such a flaw.

Answer (score 3):

As already explained, you can't do this using TToolBar due to changes in the Operating System.

However, by using ActionToolBars you can achieve what you want to achieve - even with the current version of Delphi (XE6) and Windows 8.1/2012 R2 theming.  Here's the steps:

1. Create an Action Manager
2. Add as many actions as you intend to have
3. Add an ImageList (and another optional one for Disabled Menu Items)
4. Associate each one of your actions with an image
5. Add an ActionToolBar to the form
6. Drag and drop each action you wish to appear on the toolbar to the toolbar
7. Set individual actions on the toolbar to ShowCaption := False (if desired)
8. Drag and drop the "Drag to create Separators" (from the ActionManager editor) box to add separators
9. Drag and drop the ActionClientItems (created when you drag and drop actions onto the ActionTooLBar) to where you'd like them to be.

End Result - A nice looking app with dividers betwen your icons.

[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks for taking the time to add this useful and helpful answer

Comment: We're all here to help each other :)

Comment: How is this toolbar implemented? Is it a custom VCL control?

Comment: TActionToolBar is under "Additional" along with TActionManager.

Comment: I don't have the source handy. I wonder if it's a system toolbar, wrapped by the VCL, or a full custom control, implemented in VCL code.