# Visible separators in win32 api toolbars (not just gaps)?

Tags: winapi, toolbar

I want it to look like this (just the separator)

[image: separator.png]

this is what I have:

[image: gap.png]

How would i go about doing this?

The separator at the moment is just this, nothing else in the TBBUTTON struct is set for the separator

```
tbb[3].fsStyle = TBSTYLE_SEP;
```

Comment: `TBSTYLE_SEP` is what you need. Very hard to tell from here what the problem is. You didn't show a complete program that illustrates the behaviour.

Comment: I am using TBSTYLE_SEP, but it just comes out as a gap between buttons.
I assume that's what it's meant to do, and that something else has to be done to draw a line.

Comment: Yes, you already said that. But when we use `TBSTYLE_SEP` we get separators.

Comment: With the lines?
Every example I've found just results in a space

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's on pastebin if you want to see the code http://pastebin.com/MwcN2YYp

Comment: Is your app themed? Do you have comctl32 v6 manifest?

Comment: Yes, I'm using comctl32 6 and visual stlyes. When I wasn't using visual styles I got the same result, the buttons just had a gap between them

Comment: I cannot understand this. My toolbars have divider lines. But I'm not using raw Win32 in my app. I'm not really sure that I'm being very helpful here. Sorry!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I get a line if I set TBSTYLE_FLAT, unfortunately that makes it transparent. I think this is normal behaviour: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/windows/desktop/bb760443(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I finally found the answer by reading one of my own questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645417/can-delphi-themed-toolbars-have-dividers-that-are-centred-between-their-tool-but

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Win32 control only draws vertical separator lines if the toolbar uses the flat style. So you can achieve the effect you want by including the `TBSTYLE_FLAT` style when you create the toolbar window.

Comment: ok, thanks, I also stumbled across the answer on MSDN around the same time in a somewhat unrelated screenshot showing the effect of TBSTYLE_FLAT