# Delphi tbsSeparator TToolButton on a non-themed TToolBar with Flat style has a vertical line in the middle - how to fix it?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, toolbar

My question is related to this one:

[Can Delphi themed toolbars have dividers that are centred between their tool buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645417/can-delphi-themed-toolbars-have-dividers-that-are-centred-between-their-tool-but)

I have a Delphi 7 application where I have a `TToolButton` with `Style = tbsSeparator` on a `TToolBar` with `Flat = True`. Using the fix accepted in the question mentioned above, a `tbsSeparator` and a `tbsDivider` are drawn as expected if the toolbar is themed (i.e. if my application has a theme manifest (`XPMan`) and Windows themes is enabled on the system the application is running on).

However, if the application doesn't have a manifest or if the system doesn't have themes enabled, a `tbsSeparator` is drawn with a vertical line in the middle, slightly smaller than that of a `tbsDivider`:
[image]

On the screenshot, the one on the left is a `tbsSeparator` (it shouldn't have the line in the middle), the one on the right is a `tbsDivider` (that one's OK).

If I turn off the `Flat` style everything is OK, but I want the `Flat` style on a non-themed toolbar.

So, the question is **how to have a `tbsSeparator` drawn without a vertical line in the middle on a non-themed `TToolBar` with `Flat` style**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Delphi themed toolbars have dividers that are centred between their tool buttons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645417/can-delphi-themed-toolbars-have-dividers-that-are-centred-between-their-tool-but)

Comment: @David I specifically mention that question and it solves part of the problem, but not the part I mention in this question. It solves the issue with the unnecessary line on the left in a `tbsSeparator` and a `tbsDivider` on a themed toolbar, but not the unnecessary line in the middle of a `tbsSeparator` on a non-themed toolbar. Notice that I want to keep the Flat style on a non-themed toolbar.

Comment: The point is that there is no solution. That's the conclusion from the other question.

Comment: @David I don't see such a conclusion. And this issue here is not mentioned in the other question at all. Although related, it's a different issue. The issue there is with a themed toolbar and a line on the left, the issue here is with a non-themed toolbar and a line in the middle. And the issue there has a solution.

Comment: It's just the other side of the coin. You cannot have it both ways

Comment: The question may not be a duplicate, but the first sentence of the accepted answer of the other question, answers this one. I posted the same, together with a quote from the documentation.

Comment: @Sertac thanks for clearing things up. I didn't see the msdn documentation, I only looked at the [VCL one](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TToolButton.Style) which states that tbsSeparator appears as an empty space, omitting the "or draws an etch" part. I thought the cause for the problem might be different, because the line is drawn in the middle when the toolbar is not themed and on the left when it's themed (I still don't understand why). Still, I think a better answer is to override the Paint procedure, although there might be flickering as David says.

Comment: @jedi - You're welcome.   As for why the separator line is on the left when the toolbar is themed, it's a peculiarity of visual styles if you ask me, the divider line is on the left edge of the theme part. You can verify this by drawing the part yourself, or download [Theme Explorer](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/controls/windows-xp-theme-manager) of Mike Lischke and browse to the part.

Comment: I accepted @sertac's at my question. But what I took from it is that there is no way out of the bind. Drawing yourself doesn't work out well here.

Comment: @David if you really want absolutely empty space on a non-themed Flat toolbar, drawing yourself is certainly better than nothing, despite the flickering. Many other controls flicker when resized anyway.

Comment: Nothing flickers in my apps. My perception here is that an off centre separator is the least bad solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quote from [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760443%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The BTNS_SEP style creates a small gap between buttons or draws an
>   etch between buttons on flat toolbars. ...

It states, an etch is drawn on separators of flat toolbars. There's no mention of dependency on themes..